# Which ReactJS Components or Elements should I test?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai

Hi I am developing a few SharePoint Web Parts with ReactJS and are ready to test them. Installed Mocha and Chai ok and test runs ran OK. The first two apps I am testing work as follows:
1. Search component - A jQuery Autocomplete that pulls data via the Fetch method and pushes this to the Input Div to perform searching and appends this data to some Input fields. 
2. A-Z List - A Directory type application that allows users to navigate through locations from A to Z and view particular details about each location. Again data is pulled from SharePoint list via Fetch and then objectified:

(`var myobj = data.map(item){return {value: item.title }}` ).

They both make use of Material-UI themes (MUI) and in particular - Tabs,Tables,TextField, RaisedButton,Dialog.

I also have Interfaces as mentioned in separate classes.

Now I want to test and writing a some test and want to do tests with Describe and It methods but since this is my first time doing formal software testing I was wondering a few things and need advice:

1. What high level functionality should I test?
2. If I was to begin I am thinking of testing the following elements/components:

   2a. Render method - Render()

   2b. Class definitions - export default SearchCmp extends Component

   2c. Main Divs - Important divs that need to be rendered.

   2d. Navigation in the AZ list

   2e. Fetch return - Does it equal to true?

So all in all I don't know if I am planning this right with the above areas to be included and two can you provide code sample or advice for such tests if they will be useful for me? jsdom is available too as we can't have access to real dom.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following this guidlines : NodeJS Testing with Chai and Code Quality. https://www.lynda.com/Node-js-tutorials/Assertion-libraries-correctness/587672/654554-4.html?srchtrk=index%3a1%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3achai%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2

Once finished I should be in better position to design Unit and Integration tests.